# An error occurred while creating the maze game. (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, maze

I want to express a message("end game") when the player arrives at the End point, but it doesn't work what's the problem?

Player = PlayerPictureBox;

EndPoint = endPointPictureBox;

```
   protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        bool isRoad = mazeTiles[(PlayerPictureBox.Left - 25) / TILESIZE, (PlayerPictureBox.Top - 10) / TILESIZE].BackColor != Color.Black;
  
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Left:

                if (isRoad)
                    PlayerPictureBox.Left -= 10;               
                else
                    ResetLocaiton();                
                return true;

            case Keys.Right:

                if (isRoad)
                    PlayerPictureBox.Left += 10;                      
                else
                    ResetLocaiton();
                    
                return true;

            case Keys.Up:

                if (isRoad)
                    PlayerPictureBox.Top -= 10;
                else
                    ResetLocaiton();
                   
                return true;

            case Keys.Down:

                if (isRoad)
                    PlayerPictureBox.Top += 10;  
               else
                    ResetLocaiton();
                   
                return true;
         }
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);            
      }






private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   
        if (PlayerPictureBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(endPointPictureBox.Bounds))

        {
            MessageBox.Show("end game");
        }
    }
```

I am moving the player according to the input of the direction key, and I want the message to be marked when I arrive at the arrival point, but there is an error that the message is not marked.

Comment: Your description is very unprecise/unclear. What should "it doesn't work" mean? If you don't see the message box, the condition in your if clause is likely not satisfied when the form is loaded. Did you debug this? Your description sounds like you need to use a more specific event when a specific thing happens instead of just put this in the form load event.

Comment: Does that Form1_Load method get called at the correct time? Do those boxes intersect? We cannot tell from here

Comment: I'm sorry. I've code Please give me some advice.

Comment: Can't be sure from your code, but the event Form1_Load would normally be called only once, when the form first loads.  If the criteria is not met at that time, the MessageBox won't be shown.  I can't see how you expect to reach that code again after.  Are you sure Form1_Load is handling the event you really want handled?

Comment: Based on your words, I solved the current problem by writing it in the direction key method rather than form_load Thank you.